# Elasticsearch: how to limit snowball analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

Using the snowball analyzer, I'm getting results for 'house' when I query 'housing'. I want the analyzer for most searches, but in this case, the return is irrelevant. How would I limit the work the analyzer does to account for these cases?

Comment: By "these cases", do you mean the ability to specify *specific cases* where the analyzer should limit its search?  Or is there a more general problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Good question. I think the best case scenario would be to provide an ongoing list of cases as we find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via the keyword_marker and stem_exclusion filters:

> **Preventing stemming**
>
> The stem_exclusion parameter for language analyzers (see Configuring
>   language analyzers) allowed us to specify a list of words that should
>   not be stemmed. Internally, these language analyzers use the
>   keyword_marker token filter to mark the listed words as keywords,
>   which prevents subsequent stemming token filters from touching those
>   words.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/controlling-stemming.html

> **Specifying keywords in a file**
>
> While the language analyzers only allow us to specify an array of
>   words in the stem_exclusion parameter, the keyword_marker token filter
>   also accepts a keywords_path parameter which allows us to store all of
>   our keywords in a file. The file should contain one word per line, and
>   must be present on every node in the cluster. See Updating stopwords
>   for tips on how to update this file.

This example (from the documentation) shows how to implement this:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "no_stem": {
          "type": "keyword_marker",
          "keywords": [ "skies" ] 
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_english": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "no_stem",
            "porter_stem"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The specifics will differ depending upon your existing analyzer setup but this should get you going.